# Synchronized Data Sources fields not available in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, contactbuilder

When synchronizing object's fields, some fields are missing in MC to synchronize even though they have the box visibly checked for the system administrator. These fields are:

- Account - ShippingAdress
- Contact - MailingAdress

Any ideas, please?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this field is required in CRM, then it is visually checked but not synced.
To start working with it:

- Select a needed object in Synchronised Data Sources in Contact Builder
- Click the "Edit Fields" button
- Without changing anything, click "Save".
- Navigate to the "Activity" tab on the object's page, and check if you see a new record saying that you added a new field.